# How do I exclude a package from react native link?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, command-line-interface

I currently add a module using : `npm i --save <package_name>`

and once done, I use : `react-native link` instead of `react-native link <package_name>`, there by linking all possible react native libraries present in my package.json .

The problem arrives when one of the packages I am about to use requires me to NOT USE `react-native link`

> package : react-community/react-native-maps; https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

Note mentioned in the library :

> IMPORTANT!!
>   !! DO NOT USE !! react-native link

[Link to the note](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#important)

I want this so that whoever working on my project after me **doesn't** make the **mistake** of doing `react-native link` Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For react-native-maps you shouldn't use react-native link as per their latest documentation. And there are no much workaround for this.

The temporary fix can be this:

1. After 'npm install', goto node_modules folder and open the following js file.
   **RootProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/link**
2. In link.js file, linkDependency() method add the following code:

`if (dependency.name === 'react-native-maps'){
        log.info(`linking loop break as the library is'${dependency.name}'`);
        return
      }`

3. Now run, 'react-native link'. The react-native link command will link all libraries but not the maps.

PS: Actually, we shouldn't touch any of node_modules package, but for the maps library we don't have much options to solve the issue.

Any other answers are too welcome.

Comment: You could at least automate this process by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package